# JQuery 1.3.2 vsdoc does not produce Visual Studio intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, jquery-1.3.2

In past i have worked with JQuery 1.2 vsdoc file which generates intellisense for vs2008 sp1.

I have recently downloaded latest version of JQuery 1.3.2 and JQuery 1.3.2 vsdoc file.
When i tried to get intellisense for jquery in vs2008 -
I am getting following error-

Warning 1
Error updating JScript IntelliSense: C:\Documents and Settings\sonx3d\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\jquery-1.3.2.js: Object doesn't support this property 
or method @ 2139:1

Can anyone help on this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this blog - http://blogs.ipona.com/james/archive/2009/01/14/jquery-1.3-and-visual-studio-2008-intellisense.aspx

What i did is - i have downloaded (updated) version of jquery vsdoc file and added a reference in vs2008 and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

It is working now for me. All I had to do was rename `jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js` to `jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js` and now intellisense is working.

Comment: The rename is definitely important.

Answer (score 4):

Check this link 
http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/list

Download the file **jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js** and don't use **JQuery 1.3.2 vsdoc**

Also check the last few comments from 
http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/02/24/vsdoc-for-jquery-1-3-2-now-available.aspx

That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some very useful links jQuery intellisense in Visual Studio:

- FAQ on JavaScript Intellisense:  http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/18/jscript-intellisense-faq.aspx

  It explains how the path style is important to Visual Studio, ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC.
- A fantastic overview of jQuery intellisense by Scott Guthrie:
  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For those running into an error message with:
**Error updating JScript IntelliSense: 'div.childNodes' is null or not an object**

See this blog:
**http://blog.jasonkostempski.com/2009/06/jquery-132-visual-studio-2008.html#comment-form**

This resolution will probably help up until they replace the file at google.