# jQuery - error updating JScript Intellisense

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, jquery-ui, intellisense

i have searched similar posts on google & stackoverflow to no use.
Basically, what i have is a new aspx page. I have the following files referenced in the head section.

```
jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css
jquery-1.3.2.min.js
jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js
```

Theme:smoothness 
UI Version: 1.7.2 for jQuery 1.3.2

I have nothing else going on in the page but still get the error 'error updating JScript Intellisense. I am using VS2008 SP1. Any ideas?

TIA

ps: *VS shows intellisense if i refer to 1.4.1.js & 1.4.1-vsdoc.js*

Comment: It's not this problem is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709713/jquery-1-3-2-vsdoc-does-not-produce-visual-studio-intellisense/741337#741337 It caught me out at least! I did not see that 2 at the end.

Comment: @Daniel - i tried that to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew! Issue Resolved. Finally found a solution [here](http://blog.jasonkostempski.com/2009/06/jquery-132-visual-studio-2008.html).

Step 6 did it for me.

**Update:** the above link is now dead! I think the error is "Error updating JScript IntelliSense: 'div.childNodes' is null or not an object" & i think step 6 refers to fixing this error in one of jscript files.

Comment: Answers that only contain links are terrible because the links may go bad, like this one.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hotfix for this if you include the `-vsdoc.js` file as well for 1.3.2

[You can find the hotfix here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=KB958502&DownloadId=3632) and the [`-vsdoc.js` for 1.3.2 here](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js)

Visual studio doesn't like the 1.3.2 source, but if you include that intellisense file as `jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js` in your case, it'll ignore the actual `jquery-1.3.2.min.js` file it chokes on.

Once you do this, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to update intellisense.

Comment: what's the order for including the vsdoc.js file? before or after core 1.3.2 js file?

Comment: @BhejaFry - You don't actually reference it, just include it in the project, with the hotfix VS looks for a file that matches with `-vsdoc.js` in the same directory it and will use that instead for intellisense if it finds it.

Comment: r u suggesting to rename 'jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js' to 'jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js'? hotfix has been applied to VS sometime back but still get the error.

Comment: @BhejaFry - Yep, rename it to the same name as your file with `-vsdoc` in all cases, so `jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js` in your case.

Comment: @Nick - did rename the file, hotfix applied as well, still get the warning & no intellisense.

Comment: @BhejaFry I had your same setup except not using minified for development, try using the non-minified version of jQuery?

Comment: did that too but no intellisense. i downloaded non-minified & with the renamed vsdoc file, still same issue.

Comment: Warning 1 Error updating JScript IntelliSense: 
Object doesn't support this property or method @ 2139:1

Comment: @Nick - here's more info. 'div.childNodes' is null or not an object

Comment: @BhejaFry  - You have the hotfix applied, and `jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js` and `jquery-1.3.2.js` in the same directory?  Also make sure you're referencing `jquery-1.3.2.js` in your pages.

Comment: @Nick - yep did all that but that didn't fix it. The issue is with the vsdoc file. Thanks so much for your effort & help in this matter. I found the solution when i was looking for the error in div.childnodes.

Answer (score 0):

I kept on getting these annoying JScript IntelliSense errors every time I was editing a particular .aspx file.  I couldn't disable IntelliSense, and I couldn't get the -vsdoc.js fix to work, so what I ended up doing was wrapping the target of the src attributes in inline asp tags, like so:

**before:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**after:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"%>"></script>
```

Hope that helps!

P.S. I was using Visual Studio Web Developer - Express Edition with SP1.